# Actions SDK: Invoking action using "speak to" or "ask"

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

According to Google, it is possible to invoke your own Google Action using the "speak to" and "ask" invocation commands. For example, "speak to [action name] to order a pizza". This is outlined here https://developers.google.com/actions/localization/languages-locales#trigger_phrases.

However, when using the Actions SDK, this does not seem quite so straight forward. After providing sample utterances as query patterns within the Action Package, it is not possible to make use of those sample utterances.

For example, say my query pattern looks like the following:

to order (a)? pizza

Then it would be expected that a user could say "Speak to [skill name] to order a pizza". However, this is not the case with some query patterns, and yet seemingly possible with others.

Is there anyone that could shed a light on whether this is a platform issue, or perhaps an incorrect definition of a query pattern?

Comment: Can you update your question to clarify "However, this is not the case with some query patterns, and yet seemingly possible with others." Are there examples of what works and what doesn't? It is somewhat difficult to address a vague statement such as this.